# Confusion about linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the following linear system

$$\pmatrix{1&4&7\\2&5&8\\3&6&9} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$$

A solution is $x_1 = 1$, $x_ 2=-2$ and $x_3=1$. However, matrix $A$ is singular, which should make this equation unsolvable, but clearly

$$x= \pmatrix{1\\-2\\3}$$

is a solution. How is it possible for there to exist solution when the inverse of matrix $A$ cannot even exist?

Comment: It's not a matrix equation. The unknown is not a matrix. It's a vanilla linear system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite on the contrary, the fact that $A$ is singular implies that such a solution exists.

Let $M$ be another matrix, and let's suppose that $M$ is non-singular, i.e. $M$ admits an inverse, $M^{-1}$. Suppose now you want to solve the same equation with $M$.
$$Mx=0\iff x=M^{-1}0\iff x=0$$

You'll find nothing but $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\0\\0\\\end{array}\right)$.

---

EDIT

I put here a solution of the system.
$$\pmatrix{1&4&7\\2&5&8\\3&6&9} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$$
which means
$$\pmatrix{x_1+4x_2+7x_3\\2x_1+5x_2+8x_3\\3x_1+6x_2+9x_3} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}$$
(I just perform the matrix product on the left). Substract the first line from the second line we get $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. Substitute $x_3=x_1+x_2$ into the three equations we get $x_2=-2x_1$. Then we verify that all vectors of the form $(x_1,-2x_1,x_1)$ are solutions of this system.

Answer (score 1):

If it singular, why do you think that it has no solution ? It will have infinitely many solutions. All element of $$\{(x,-2x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}=\text{Span}\{(1,-2,1)\},$$
is a solution. By the way, the vector $(1,-2,3)^T$ is not a solution.

Comment: Can you explain how I can obtain (x, -2x, x) from the above linear system.

Comment: Just solve the system... @hiccup

Answer (score 0):

Recall, or correct the idea you have, maybe:

> The system of equations will have non-trivial solutions (that is not
>   all $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are zeros) if the coefficient matrix is singular.

In this case, the coefficient matrix is singular, and therefore it has a non-trivial solution, that is $x_1=1, x_2=-2, x_3=3$.

Comment: Which method do I use to find that non-trivial solution? Since I cannot do it normally by inverting A.

Comment: @hiccup: Just Gaussian elimination (which *is* the normal method, you shouldn't invert the matrix in general).